# Creating a Django demo-user who can't save to the database

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a Django web application on which users can create an account for free. I have also set-up a demo user which is already configured and has data attached to its account. Purpose of this demo account is to give a new user a quick overview of what the application can do.

Now I would like to have this demo user access all my views but not save to the database when the user saves a form.

Off course there are multiple ways off doing this that I know off. But they all require me to edit multiple pages or views:

- When saving a form check if it is the demo user, if yes: don't save
- Remove the save button from my templates when the demo user is logged in

Is there a easier/cleaner solution to do this? How can I set-up my application in a way that a specific user can never save to the database?

**The solution I used**

marcusshep's idea provided a solution for me. I created the following Views for pages where the form should be loaded but not saved when hitting the save button. Until now I wasn't able to do that. At this moment the pages below will render a 303 immediately

```
class FormViewOPRadio(FormView):
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Return 403 for demo user
    temp = 'temp'
    if self.request.user.email == 'demo@opradio.nl':
        raise PermissionDenied
    else:
        return super(FormViewOPRadio, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class UpdateViewOPRadio(UpdateView):
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Return 403 for demo user
    temp = 'temp'
    if self.request.user.email == 'demo@opradio.nl':
        raise PermissionDenied
    else:
        return super(UpdateViewOPRadio, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class DeleteViewOPRadio(DeleteView):
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Return 403 for demo user
    temp = 'temp'
    if self.request.user.email == 'demo@opradio.nl':
        raise PermissionDenied
    else:
        return super(DeleteViewOPRadio, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Furthermore there are also some pages which should be inaccessible for which I used

```
from braces.views import UserPassesTestMixin

class UserNotDemoUser(UserPassesTestMixin):
raise_exception = True

def test_func(self, user):
    return user.email != 'demo@opradio.nl'
```

**What I tried**

I created the following Views for pages where the form should be loaded but not saved when hitting the save button

```
class FormViewOPRadio(FormView):
def form_valid(self, form):
    # Return 403 for demo user
    if self.request.user.email == 'demo@opradio.nl':
        raise PermissionDenied
    else:
        return super(FormViewOPRadio, self).form_valid(form)

class AddStream(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, FormViewOPRadio):
"""Is the page used to add a Stream"""
template_name = 'opradioapp/addoreditstream.html'
form_class = AddStreamForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('opradioapp_home')
success_message = "De stream is opgeslagen"

# Validate if the user is the maintainer of the station
def test_func(self):
    user = self.request.user
    mainuserstation = MainUserStation.objects.get(slugname=self.kwargs['mainuserstationslug'])
    if mainuserstation.maintainer == user:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def form_valid(self, form):
    user = self.request.user
    mainuserstation = MainUserStation.objects.get(slugname=self.kwargs['mainuserstationslug'])
    userstream = UserStream()
    userstream.mainuserstation = mainuserstation
    userstream.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    userstream.slugname = 'temp'
    userstream.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
    userstream.save()

    member = Member.objects.get(user=user, mainuserstation=mainuserstation)
    member.streamavailable.add(userstream)
    member.save()
    return super(AddStream, self).form_valid(form)
```

When doing it this way

```
        if self.request.user.email == 'demo@opradio.nl':
        raise PermissionDenied
```

is called after the save() calls. How can I change this? I tried calling super earlier but than I ran into problems.

Comment: Does this mean that you are adding the `def dispatch() ` to each view that has a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Off course there are multiple ways of doing this that I know of. But they all require me to edit multiple pages or views:

Well, you won't have to repeat the logic for every template or view if you utilize certain [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) features of Python and Django.

[Class Based View Inheritance](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/inheritance)

```
class CheckForDemoUser(View):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # check for demo user
        # handle which ever way you see fit.
        super(CheckForDemoUser, self).dispatch(request, *a, **kw)

class ChildClass(CheckForDemoUser): # notice inheritance here
    def get(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # continue with normal request handling
        # this view will always check for demo user
        # without the need to repeat yourself.
```

[Function Decorators](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/)

```
def check_for_demo_user(func):
   def func_wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
       # implement logic to determine what the view should
       # do if the request.user is demo user.
   return func_wrapper


@check_for_demo_user
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # automatic checking happening before view gets to this point.
```

With [Inclusion Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) you can isolate the logic of hiding/showing form submit buttons in one place and refer to your custom tag in multiple pages that the demo user would be on.

These are just some of the ways you can implement this logic without having to repeat yourself over and over.

Comment: As I'm using CB views I used the first solution. I added my solutions to the original question.

Comment: I actually encountered that this wasn't working the way I expected. The PermissionDenied was rendered but the form was already saved. So the function are called in the wrong order. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Create a new question